# How do I know if my data violate the assumption of independence?

Tags: anova, assumptions, independence

I have data on reaction time (dependent variable, continuous) from participants viewing a visual stimulus that can have 7 different states (-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, independent variable, nominal). I want to answer the question if there's an effect of the previous state on the reaction time during the subsequent trial. (And explore any interaction.)

For instance, the previous state was -3 and the next state was 1. Will the reaction time be affected by that -3? Would it be different if the previous state was a 0 instead?

I have in total 3 independent variables I want to analyse: 1) previous state 2) absolute size of state change (from 1 to 6), and 3) duration of previous state (nominal, binned to short, medium, long). I also have the one dependent variable, reaction time.

My question is, can I analyse this data with statistical tests that assume independence of observations? Of course an N-way ANOVA would be great for this, given that the data is normal enough, but it appears as though I can't use that since the data are potentially violating the independence assumption. What tests should I use to analyse this data if the independence assumption was not met? My conundrum stems from the fact that I am actually trying to find if there's an effect, which is a bit circular since the test I'd use to analyse the data should then depend on the results of those tests, although I may be misunderstanding how the assumption works.

Thank you!

Sample data table: (I'm not sure if I coded this correctly)

| Reaction Time (s) | Previous State | Current State | Absolute Step Size | Previous Step Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.45 | 0 | 1 | 1 | short |
| 0.22 | 1 | -2 | 3 | long |
| 1.65 | -2 | 3 | 5 | short |
| 3.09 | 3 | 0 | 3 | medium |
| 1.55 | 0 | 1 | 1 | short |

Comment: If you have several participants, each with multiple responses, you have repeated measurements data (panel data/longitudinal data are synonyms). Then you really have two questions: Are participants independent? Are multiple responses from the same participant independent?

Comment: The participants are independent, drawn randomly, the issue at hand is not between-groups independence but rather within-groups independence (within the trials of one participant).

Comment: Please do not give new information only in comments, edit 
 your question to add the new information. We want posts to 
 be self-contained, comments can be deleted, and anyhow, 
 information in comments are not well organized. Also, many 
 people do not read comments.